# Excel: How to ask if the date in the cell is the current year and month?

Tags: excel

I have a column (for example from A1 to A10) with dates.
The structure is always the same ->
**Cell A1** = **2019-02-01 till 2021-10-23** -> See the following Example

If the actual month and year ( today is october 2020) is equal to the second date entry of A1 (2021-10-23) the font color of cell A1 should be red.

How can I do this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing formatting based on the content of a cell is easily done via conditional formatting.
Pick your top cell, add a conditional formatting (start ribbon), pick new  rule and pick the last one, based on formula.

If the structure is always exactly the same, you could find the last date using functions like `LEFT()` or `MID()`
I'm not great with those, and had some problems matching text with dates, and had to use `TEXT()`.
There's probably a nicer way to write it, but I ended up with something like this;
if `A1` contained `2019-02-01 till 2020-10-23`

```
=AND(MID(A1;17;4)=TEXT(YEAR(TODAY());"#");MID(A1;22;2)=TEXT(MONTH(TODAY());"#")
```

And then pick a formatting to apply with the formula returns true.

Comment: =IF(AND(MONTH(TODAY()) = B12, YEAR(TODAY()) = B11),0,1) -> B12 =11 and B11=2009... it does not work i dont know why.... but i understood a lot

Comment: You probably don't need an and with the if, it's kind of built in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask for the date of today, using `TODAY()` or `NOW()` function. There also are the functions `Year()` and `Month()` to find the year and month number of a date. Combining all those should solve your question.

Comment: ok, does it really work if in one cell are two dates? i tried it but i does not work so far.... can you help me more? thx